# Mockito - nested method invoked multiple times

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have service class with method which calls ie. `repository.save()` multiple times. I am testing said service method. Is it possible to capture `save()` method call on `x` time and get its passed/returned arguments?

Example:

```
class MyService{

    void doSomething(){
        myRepository.save(obj1);
        // some code;
        myRepository.save(obj2);
    }

}
```

I am testing `doSomething` method and would like to get result and/or passed argument of the first save method. I am using mockito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the previous answer, I assume that `myRepository` is of type `MyRepository`, is mocked and passed to `myService`. You can capture and check the arguments passed to the method `save()` using an [`ArgumentCaptor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html):

```java
    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {

        // Given
        MyRepository myRepository = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
        MyService myService = new MyService(myRepository);

        // When
        myService.doSomething();

        // Then
        ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
        Mockito.verify(myRepository, Mockito.times(2)).save(captor.capture());

        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, captor.getAllValues().get(0)); // First invocation of save()
        Assert.assertEquals(obj2, captor.getAllValues().get(1)); // Second invocation of save()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you pass `myRepository` as a dependency to `MyService`. In that case you can create a mock of it in your test and pass that mock instead.

You can call `Mockito.doAnswer(...).when(myRepository).save(any())` and pass an `Answer` that handles the `save` call of your mocked `myRepository`. If you need to execute the actual method of the `myRepository` object, you can add a `doCallRealMethod()` to the chain.

The argument passed to the `Answer` is the invocation and you can get the arguments using `invocation.getArguments()`.

**Update**: @Benoit's answer seems to be a lot more elegant as the `ArgumentCaptor` doesn't require extra logic to find out if it was the first or second call.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get first method call? I handled `when(myRepo.save()).return(...)`, but I want to check passed object to the first `repo.save` method call. I am not interested in other same method calls after the first one, nor am I interested in testing that particular method detached from my `doSomething` method.

Comment: @Aline137 you'll have to use logic inside the `answer` method to decide whether it's the first or second call. For example you could toggle a boolean (true for the first call, false for the second call) - assuming you only call `save` within `MyService`.